# MKV Video File Segment Title Renaming Software

Tags: windows-7, video, video-editing

I'm currently having to use mvkmerge GUI under the Global options to rename titles of each of my movie clips and it takes a great deal of time to do so since it has to create an entirely different file to do so.

Is there a piece of software that can quickly edit File / Segment Titles instead of having to recreate the file all over again.

Example: files that are around 10 GB take around 1-2 minutes to be recreated, I'm wondering if there is a better method, or a method to simply edit the same file that should take a matter of seconds since it's just the action of renaming a string of code.

Thanks.

Comment: Any luck finding something?

Comment: @alexs nope. But that project is over now for me. GL